# Accessing Request.QueryString[foo] is null but the URL shows the query string/parameter is right there

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling an .aspx script through AJAX. In that script I am attempting to get a value from the query string using `Request.QueryString["i"]` but it always returns null even though, if I examine the Request object in debug mode, the query string **IS** right there.

**Whats going wrong & how can I retrieve the `i` parameter value from testScript.aspx?i=199?**

Heres my simple code:

```
    public partial class getData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            short index = System.Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["i"]);  // BREAKPOINT
        }
    }
```

When I use a break point & examine the Request Object I can see that the `Request.QueryString` variable is empty(just a {}). `Request.QueryString["i"]` is null.

**If you look at the following img you can see the *form* has my `i` parameter(thats my query string `.aspx?i=4`**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your form is sent using **POST** request, and parameter **i** is not in QueryString but in request body encoded using multipart form data format,`Request.QueryString` only show's parameters passed through URI like page.asax?i=4. Use `Request.Form["i"]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing the query string with form fields. In the screenshot, your value "i" is clearly on the `Form` property.

Form fields are fields on the page which are POSTed, as opposed to the query string items, which appear at the end of the url.

If you look at the `QueryString` property, I suspect you won't find your item.

Try using:

```
Request.Form["i"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Jake u are used post method, and in post method query string not worked, so u have to user either get method to use query string or if u are used post method then change your code in testScript.aspx load event **Request.QueryString to Request.Form** like this

```
public partial class getData : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        short index = System.Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["i"]);  // BREAKPOINT
    }
}
```